# how does class 0 scores in the classification report are calculated ( sklearn python )?

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn

Here how these class-0 probability are calculated??

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
class 1       1.00      0.67      0.80         3
```

avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61         4

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) for the classification_report function.

- The first measure shown is **precision**: n(True positive) / (n(True positive) + n(False positive)
- The second measure shown is **recall**: n(True positive) / (n(True positive)) + n(False negative)
- The third one is **F1 score**: 2* (Precision * Recall)/(Precision + Recall)

Comment: Thanks for your response. yeah for **precison_class0** = TN/(TN+FN) and for **precision_class1** = TP/(TP+FP).